# Is it possible to tell if a transaction involves an ERC721 token if the only information you have is the transaction address from Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, erc721

Right now I have a web socket that's subscribed to all pending transactions. I was wondering if I'm able to figure out if I'm able to decide if a particular transaction involves an ERC721 token with the object that gets returned.

I was looking into Etherscan recently and I realized that a lot of the data Etherscan displays seems pretty challenging to retrieve and was wondering how Etherscan's ERC721 token transfer feature is implemented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can we get token holders from token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68860386/how-can-we-get-token-holders-from-token)

Comment: TLDR: Etherscan reads the `Transfer()` events emitted in each token transferring transaction and build a separate database of token transfers. This applies to both ERC20 and ERC721.